# Product Grid Breaking With Image Banner - CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to put an image banner into a category page of an ecommerce store that has a grid of products.

See here: http://www.gardensgalore.net.au/Garden-Beds/

I want the banner to appear on the right (which is the grey box image) so it is set to float right. The top two images work the way I want them to, but the row underneath doesn't quite "wrap" around the image the way I want.

If I change the .product-grid li class to float:right; instead of float:left; it does exactly what I want it to, except if you scroll to the bottom it looks strange having the last image floating on the right instead of the left.

What sort of styles should I have in place to make the images "wrap" around the banner, whilst still making sure products float to the left?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove clear : left from  .product-grid li:nth-child() //line no 7986

and set banner height : 875px & width = 457px